# How to Transform Column to Row

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @InputJsonData VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @InputJsonData='[{"MemberNumber":8,"M1":"2018 January","M1Days":2,"M1Duration":"2 h 54 m","M1Amount":"-$712.62","M2":"2018 February","M2Days":5,"M2Duration":"4 h 32 m","M2Amount":"$1,359.53"},{"MemberNumber":75,"M1":"2018 January","M1Days":2,"M1Duration":"2 h 54 m","M1Amount":"-$712.62","M2":"2018 February","M2Days":5,"M2Duration":"4 h 32 m","M2Amount":"$1,359.53"}]'

DECLARE @MemberDetail TABLE(MemberID VARCHAR(12),M1 VARCHAR(24),M1Days INT,M1Duration VARCHAR(24),M1Amount MONEY
,M2 VARCHAR(24),M2Days INT,M2Duration VARCHAR(24),M2Amount MONEY
)

INSERT INTO @MemberDetail
SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@InputJsonData)
                 WITH (MemberNumber VARCHAR(12) '$.MemberNumber'
                       ,M1 VARCHAR(24) '$.M1'   
                       ,M1Days INT '$.M1Days'
                       ,M1Duration VARCHAR(24) '$.M1Duration'
                       ,M1Amount MONEY '$.M1Amount'
                       ,M2 VARCHAR(24) '$.M2'   
                       ,M2Days INT '$.M2Days'
                       ,M2Duration VARCHAR(24) '$.M2Duration'
                       ,M2Amount MONEY '$.M2Amount'                    
                       )

SELECT * FROm @MemberDetail
```

My Answer Be Like :

```
MemberID    M1             M1Days   M1Duration  M1Amount    
8          2018 January    2        2 h 54 m    -712.62 
8          2018 February   5        4 h 32 m    1359.53
75         2018 January    2        2 h 54 m    -712.62 
75         2018 February   5        4 h 32 m    1359.53
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are using MySQL (which you tagged)? This looks like SQL Server syntax.

Comment: I am Using MsSql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` to unpivot the data:

```
SELECT md.MemberId, v.*
FROm @MemberDetail md CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (md.M1, md.M1Days, md.M1Duration, md.M1Amount),
             (md.M2, md.M2Days, md.M2Duration, md.M2Amount)
     ) v(M, MDays, MDuration, MAmount)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL as below to achieve your requirement-

```
SELECT M1,M1Days,M1Duration,M1Amount FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT M2 AS M1,M2Days AS M1Days,M2Duration AS M1Duration,M2Amount AS M1Amount FROM 
your_table
```